# When to switch from drawRect: to OpenGL/Metal?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, drawrect, 2d-games, metal

I've been building a 2D game and I've been drawing the playing area inside of a `UIView`subclass where I override `drawRect:` and draw the game with a lot of `UIBezierPath*` objects. I'm not very experienced on iOS and I've been wondering if this is the right way to do it.

So I guess my question is How much is enough? When should I stop using `UIBezierPath`and start using OpenGL or Metal? Can I use these to draw inside an `UIView`or they take total control of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no answer on when you should stop using `UIBezierPath`. You need to ask yourself in the beginning on what tool will you need to use to achieve what you need for your application to work the way you want it to. The core graphics procedure which you use is very simple comparing to `openGL` or such but the performance is not at its best and mostly you are very limited on what you can even achieve in drawing. In general you should use as easy procedure as possible as long as it works out for you.

OpenGL and Metal are bond to the view and do not take control of your whole window (the screen in iOS). Also you can still add subviews to those views without breaking any drawing or functionality so for instance even a full screen view openGL application can have a simple `UIButton` to for instance pause the game or make your main character take that big sword and slay the dragon saving the princess.

Comment: English is not my native language and I had a hard time trying to make my doubt clear, but you did answer exactly what I needed to know. Thank you very much! By the way, I think Metal only works on A7+, right?

Comment: Yes, it is very limited for now. The supported devices are listed here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html